# How can I detect an unmanaged C++ project in a visual studio extension

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions, envdte

In my Visual Studio Extension, I need to detect whether a C++ project is managed or unmanaged code.

Previously, I had a satisfactory method, described in [this posting](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsx/thread/89a84ca0-cab6-4477-ba68-7e134c32529a/) in an MSDN forum.

In that example, it was necessary to get the **ManagedExtensions** property of the active configuration.

```
Sub Macro1() 

  Dim objProject As EnvDTE.Project 
  Dim objConfiguration As EnvDTE.Configuration 
  Dim objProperty As EnvDTE.Property 

  For Each objProject In DTE.Solution.Projects 
      objConfiguration = objProject.ConfigurationManager.ActiveConfiguration() 
      objProperty = objConfiguration.Properties.Item("ManagedExtensions") 
      System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(objProject.Name & " (" & objConfiguration.ConfigurationName & ") ManagedExtensions: " & objProperty.Value.ToString) 
  Next 

End Sub
```

Unfortunately, this method is no longer working for me.

For unmanaged projects, I get an exception trying to fetch the ActiveConfiguration.

For managed projects, I can get the ActiveConfiguration, but the ManagedExtensions property is not available. In fact, I think that the properties collection is empty.

Is there a new way to recognize an unmanaged C++ project?

Comment: If you are going to vote a question down, it would be nice if you would suggest how I could improve the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the ManagedExtensions property via the VCConfiguration object, with code something like

```
Private Enum compileAsManagedOptions
  managedNotSet            = 0
  managedAssembly          = 1
  managedAssemblyPure      = 2
  managedAssemblySafe      = 3
  managedAssemblyOldSyntax = 4
End Enum


Dim VCProj            As Object                   'VCProject
Dim VCConfig          As Object                   'VCConfiguration
Dim VCManagedOption   As compileAsManagedOptions = compileAsManagedOptions.managedAssemblyPure

VCProj = prj.Object
If VCProj IsNot Nothing Then
  VCConfig = VCProj.Configurations.Item(1)
  If VCConfig IsNot Nothing Then
    VCManagedOption = VCConfig.ManagedExtensions
  End If
End If
```

where prj is the Envdte.Project object.

This code is only executed if I already know that it is a C++ project, based on the project kind.

I defined the variables as object, so that I don't have to add a reference to
Microsoft.VisualStudio.VCProject.dll
to my package, because this DLL will only be present if support for C++ projects has been installed.